# How to correctly override supportedInterfaceOrientations in a Navigation Controller iOS 10?

Tags: ios

I am subclassing `UINavigationController` and overriding the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method. In that method, I delegate to the `visibleViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations`.
However, when I present a `UIImagePickerController` modally, then `visibleViewController` is nil.
 Something changed in iOS 10 causing `visibleViewController` to return nil.
If I change the code to use `presentedViewController` it correctly returns the `UIImagePickerController`.
Is this the correct change to make? Why did this change?

Comment: Technically the "correct" way would be using the `UITraitCollection` and `UITraitEnvironment` APIs...

Comment: @l'L'l If you could post an example of that, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could use `setOverrideTraitCollection(_:forChildViewController:)` — — 
( I would imagine you could implement something similar with the `UIImagePickerController` ):

```
func setOverrideTraitCollection(_ collection: UITraitCollection?, 
     forChildViewController childViewController: UIViewController)
```

> Normally, traits are passed unmodified from the parent view controller
>   to its child view controllers. When implementing a custom container
>   view controller, you can use this method to change the traits of any
>   embedded child view controllers to something more appropriate for your
>   layout. Making such a change alters other view controller behaviors
>   associated with that child. For example, modal presentations behave
>   differently in a horizontally compact versus horizontally regular
>   environment. You might also make such a change to force the same set
>   of traits on the child view controller regardless of the actual trait
>   environment.
>
> ↪︎ Video Presentation from WWDC 2016 : [Making Apps Adaptive, Part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/222/) and [2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/233/)

Apple has [*recommended*](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiinterfaceorientationmask#overview) to use the newer APIs **[`UITraitCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitraitcollection)** and [**`UITraitEnvironment`**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitraitenvironment) over trying to adapt `supportedInterfaceOrientations` moving forward...

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thanks for the resources. I'll check them out.